# Calculating Hourly Averages for multiple data columns

Tags: text-processing

Good day, I would like to calculate hourly averages for the follwing sample data:

```
Timestamp,data1,data2
2018 07 16 13:00:00,23,451
2018 07 16 13:10:00,26,452
2018 07 16 13:20:00,24,453
2018 07 16 13:30:00,23,454
2018 07 16 13:50:00,28,455
2018 07 16 14:20:00,20,456
2018 07 16 14:40:00,12,457
2018 07 16 14:50:00,22,458
2018 07 16 15:10:00,234,459
2018 07 16 17:50:00,23,845
2018 07 16 18:10:00,239,453
2018 07 17 10:10:00,29,452
2018 07 18 13:20:00,49,451
2018 07 19 13:30:00,28,456
```

desired output:

```
Date,Hour,Ave_data1,Ave_data2
2018 07 16,13,24.8,453
2018 07 16,14,18,457
2018 07 16,15,234,459
2018 07 16,17,23,845
2018 07 16,18,239,453
2018 07 17,10,29,452
2018 07 18,13,49,451
2018 07 19,13,28,456
```

Please note that data goes on for days (100000+ records) and data columns vary, sometimes there's more than 2 columns (i.e. data1,data2,...,dataX). So i would like the script to be able to do calculations even when there are more columns. your help will be highly appreciated.

PS: Before posting this, i checked old posts and they dont really address my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

my $prev = '';
my (@sums,@avg) = ();
my $count = 0;

while(<>) {
  chomp;
  if (m/^Timestamp/) {
    my @headers = split /,/;
    # insert "Ave_" at start of each header
    @headers = map { "Ave_" . $_ } @headers;
    # replace Timestamp header with Date,Hour headers.
    splice @headers,0,1,qw(Date Hour);
    print join(",",@headers), "\n";
    next;
  };

  my (@data) = split /,/;
  # extract and remove date and hour from first element of @data
  (my $current = shift @data) =~  s/^(.*) (\d\d):.*$/$1,$2/;

  if ($count == 0 || $current eq $prev) {
    # add each field in @data to the same field in @sums
    foreach my $i (0..$#data) { $sums[$i] += $data[$i] };
    $prev = $current;
    $count++;
    next unless eof;
  };

  # calculate and print the averages for the previous hour
  foreach my $i (0..$#sums) { $avg[$i] = $sums[$i] / $count };
  print join(",", $prev, @avg), "\n";

  # special case handling for when there's a new date/hour on the
  # last line of file (otherwise it wouldn't get printed)
  if (eof && $prev ne $current) {
    print join(",", $current, @data), "\n";
  };

  @sums = @data;
  @avg = ();
  $prev = $current;
  $count = 1;
};
```

This should work with any number of data fields.

Save as, e.g., `average.pl`, make it executable with `chmod +x average.pl` and run like:

```
$ ./average.pl input.csv 
Date,Hour,Ave_data1,Ave_data2
2018 07 16,13,24.8,453
2018 07 16,14,18,457
2018 07 16,15,234,459
2018 07 16,17,23,845
2018 07 16,18,239,453
2018 07 17,10,29,452
2018 07 18,13,49,451
2018 07 19,13,28,456
```

---

###### Extra interesting (IMO) stuff about perl and `map` and loops and iterators:

FYI, the `foreach my $i ...` loops could be re-written to use perl's `map` function instead (see `perldoc -f map`, but in short: `map` iterates over a list, doing stuff with each element, and returning either a new generated list or a count of the elements in that generated list).  This is more idiomatically perl, but is probably harder to understand for new perl programmers.  e.g.

```perl
     foreach my $i (0..$#data) { $sums[$i] += $data[$i] };

could be written as:

     @sums = map { $sums[$_] + $data[$_] } 0..$#data;
```

Both of these iterate over the **indices** of the @data array (`0..$#data`).  The for loop creates/modifies the elements of @sums directly, while the `map` returns a new array of sums which is then assigned to the @sums array.

Instead of using `$i` as the iterator variable, the `map` function automatically creates and uses a (localised) scalar variable called `$_`.  `$_` is used everywhere in perl, and is the implicit (i.e. default) argument to most functions when an argument isn't provided.   e.g. `print` without an argument is actually `print $_`, and `split /,/` is actually `split /,/, $_`. It's also implicit for pattern matching operators, e.g. `s/foo/bar` is actually `$_ =~ s/foo/bar/`.

Similarly, `while (<>)` is actually something like `while (defined($_ = <>))` (i.e. read a line from the input file or stdin, and if there was anything to read, assign it to $_ and evaluate as true. Otherwise evaluate as false and end the `while` loop).

`$_` is often informally called "the current thing" or "thingy".  See `man perlvar` and search for `\$_` for more details.  There's also an array equivalent `@_`, which is used for the parameters passed to a subroutine.

```perl
  foreach my $i (0..$#sums) { $avg[$i] = $sums[$i] / $count };

could be written as:

  @avg = map { $_ / $count } @sums;
```

Here, the `foreach` loop iterates over the **indices** of @sums (`0..$#sums`), while the `map` iterates over the **values** of the `@sums` array.  Again, the `foreach` loop modifies each element of the `@avg` array directly, while the `map` returns a new array which is assigned to `@avg`.

Both forms produce identical output in this script, and both forms are useful, but perl programmers tend towards using `map` over time because it's a generically useful tool for iterating over any kind of list.  And shorter to type than a for/foreach loop that does the same thing.  And because, after a while, it becomes natural to think about your data in terms of lists, arrays, and hashes.

It's often used for transforming an array into a hash (or the values or keys of a hash into an array).

BTW, `map` doesn't have to return an array, the code block in the `{ ... }` can do anything that perl code can do, and the return value could be just discarded or (if assigned to a scalar variable) return a count of any generated list.

e.g. the first foreach loop could also be written as:

```
map { $sums[$_] += $data[$_] } 0..$#data;
```

This modifies the @sums array directly (just like the foreach loop does), and any return value is discarded (i.e. not assigned to any variable).

And, of course, the second `foreach` loop could also be written as:

```
map { $avg[$_] = $sums[$_] / $count } 0..$#sums;
```

Answer (score 1):

A `GNU awk` way:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS=","
}

NR == 1 {
    # Build the header here
    for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) oh = oh OFS "Ave_" $i
    
    print "Date", "Hour" oh
    next
}

{
    # Split date and time and build a timestamp with it.
    # Set MM and SS to 0 to aggregate data from the same hour
    split($1, a, " ")
    sub(/:.*/, "", a[4])
    ct = mktime(a[1] " " a[2] " " a[3] " " a[4] " 00 00")

    # If the 'current time' differ from the 'old time' then
    # do the average and print the line
    if (ct != ot && ot) {
        for (i in avg){
            avg_h = avg_h OFS (avg[i] / cnt[i])
            delete avg[i]
            delete cnt[i]
        }

        sub(/^,/, "", avg_h)
        print cd, ch, avg_h
        avg_h = ""
        saved = 0
    }

    j = 0
    for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) {
        avg[j] += $i
        cnt[j++] += 1
    }

    # Do the assignment if and only something has changed
    if (!saved) {
        saved = 1
        ot = ct
        cd = a[1] " " a[2] " " a[3]
        ch = a[4]
    }
}

END {
    # There are something else? Print it
    for (i in avg)
        avg_h = avg_h OFS (avg[i] / cnt[i])

    sub(/^,/, "", avg_h)
    print cd, ch, avg_h
}
```

Run as : `./script.awk data`